# Etsy API Integration with custom ERP

Tags: c#, api, etsy

I'm trying to use the Etsy API to get orders and product data into my web app. The application is in C#. My problem is that Etsy will not approve my API app because their terms state the following.

we do not allow 3rd party apps to ask shop owners to make their own API keys to use the service. Instead, we require 3rd party apps to implement [Oauth Authentication](https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/essentials/authentication/) to make the connection.

In the documentation on the above link one of the variables that has to be passed is client_id which is the Keystring that you get when you create an API app from inside Etsy that has to be approved in order to use it.

I am more than confused with all of the above and what should i do because every time i try to create an API app it gets rejected because in the website url i insert, adding my web app and they inform me that it has been rejected due to third party app.

I don't quite understand the existance of an API with restrictions of third party apps because i believe its against its nature.

Does anyone done the above in order to help me or to point to me something that i dont understand?

Answer (score 0):

The keystring they're talking about in the above link is one that you are provided with when you register your app with Etsy, not something you get through the API. Initially, this will only allow you to access your own store, so you use this access to develop and debug your application. When your app is ready, you then apply for commercial access which will allow other people to use you app to access their own stores (after granting your app access).

Comment: The thing is they won't approve my app in order to use that keystring and after testing to covert it to commercial. Does anyone done it in order to provide me instructions?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how OAuth works. If you register your app, develop it and have it approved, then your end users do not ever need to enter their own API keys. From the information you have provided the reason your app will not be approved is that you **are** asking users to enter their API keys.